# Random number generator that will always give all numbers within the specified range?

Tags: python, random

Is there a way to generate random intergers like with `random.randint(i, j)` but where it will always return all numbers within the range, without repetition and in random order ?

e.g:
(0,6) would give me 5, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1

`random.randint(i, j)` does not do it.

Comment: Shuffle a `range`…?!

Comment: The book "Graphics Gems", edited by Andrew Glassner, contains an implementation of a "digital dissolve" effect which has, at its core, a method of returning all integers 0 <= x < 2^n in "random-looking" order, with very little extra storage. Apparently, someone has [turned it into JavaScript](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/dissolve-generator).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```py
def random_range(begin: int, end: int) -> list[int]:
    nums: list[int] = list(range(begin, end + 1))
    random.shuffle(nums)
    return nums
```

The `+ 1` is to account for the last number, you can remove it though if you want to get it IN the range, not THE range